# Knockoutjs: Accessing property of observable object

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

I'm new to knockoutjs and I'm following the Microsoft tutorial on how to use knockoutjs with MVC Web API located here: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-8. This step in the tutorial explains how to assign a "Book" object to an observable, then explains that to bind the object's properties to html, I would access the AuthorName property like this:

```
data-bind="text: detail().AuthorName"
```

The observable and ajax call looks like this:

```
self.detail = ko.observable();

self.getBookDetail = function (item) {
    ajaxHelper(booksUri + item.Id, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.detail(data);
    });
}

function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.error(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

My question is what if I want to access the AuthorName property from javascript? I thought it would be something like this but this doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if it's just a syntax issue or something more complicated:

```
self.detail().AuthorName
```

This entire source code for this sample project can be downloaded here: https://github.com/MikeWasson/BookService

Comment: What is AuthorName and how is it assigned? If it's an observable you'll have to call it like a function. self.detail().AuthorName(). In the mark-up this is done automatically by the binding, but from javascript you have to unwrap observable values manually.

Comment: @JasonSpake AuthorName comes from the JSON data, which comes from my MVC controller. Once it reaches client side, the entire Book object is assigned to self.detail. But I having problems trying to access AuthorName via self.detail().AuthorName and also tried self.detail().AuthorName() in javascript, not markup.

Comment: Then it should work the same. I suggest you console.log the contents of self.detail() and see if it's even in there

Answer (score 2):

Below there are two snippets with a sample UI, that try to simulate that you are looking for. I suspect that either you don't have set up correctly the view model with the apply bindings or you don't call the getBookDetail method.

```js
function ViewModel(){
    self = this;
  
    self.detail = ko.observable();

    self.getBookDetail = function () {
        var book = { AuthorName: 'foo', Category: 'bar'};
        self.detail(book);
    }
    
    self.getBookDetail();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text:detail().AuthorName"></div>
```

```js
function ViewModel(){
    self = this;
  
    self.detail = ko.observable();

    self.getBookDetail = function () {
        var book = { AuthorName: 'foo', Category: 'bar'};
        self.detail(book);
    }
   
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text:detail() !== undefined ? detail().AuthorName : '' "></div>
<input type="button" value="click" data-bind="click: getBookDetail"/>
```

Comment: My question was more how to access AuthorName from javascript. Is it the same syntax as you have in the markup? self.detail().AuthorName?

Answer (score 0):

`self.detail().AuthorName` should work just fine but you need to make sure `self.detail()` isn't returning `null` or something that doesn't have the property `AuthorName` on it.